# How to get OWL explanation with Drools engine?

Tags: drools, owl-api, swrlapi

I'm using OWLAPI along with SWRLAPI to build ontologies with SWRL rules and perform some SQWRL queries. Fot that, I use something like:

```
SQWRLQueryEngine queryEngine = SWRLAPIFactory.createSQWRLQueryEngine(onto);
sqwrlResult = queryEngine.runSQWRLQuery("q1","idsm:is_Permitted(?x) -> sqwrl:select(?x)");
```

I get right answers, i.e. `idsm:is_Permitted(op)` axioms are well inferred from SWRL rules by the SQWRL engine. But now, I would like to get OWL explanations for "how those axioms were inferred".

I found the OWL explanation API (https://github.com/matthewhorridge/owlexplanation), but I only found examples using Pellet or HermiT. Is it possible to get explanations from Drools engine too ? If I execute `queryEngine.getOWLReasoner()` I then get an exception "reasoner not yet wired up". And if I execute `queryEngine.getOWL2RLEngine()` I get an object from class `OWL2RLEngine` that is different of the class `OWLReasoner`.

The code I found is:

```
OWLReasonerFactory rf = ...;

// Create the explanation generator factory which uses reasoners provided by the specified
// reasoner factory
ExplanationGeneratorFactory<OWLAxiom> genFac = ExplanationManager.createExplanationGeneratorFactory(rf, null);

// Now create the actual explanation generator for our ontology
ExplanationGenerator<OWLAxiom> gen = genFac.createExplanationGenerator(onto);
```

Ok. What should I put for `rf` variable to "connect" to the Drools engine ?

Thanks for your help,
Manu

Comment: Drools doesn't natively support owl/swrl. So the answer for your question at the bottom of the post is "nothing". You'd need to find either a library that implements swrlapi or owlapi with drools, or build it out yourself.

Comment: To add to Roddy's comment, a library would need to implement OWLReasoner on top of SWRL. I'd start by looking at SWRLApi source code, as it's the most likely place to find inspiration. "Reasoner not wired yet" might suggest there's partial work already in place.

Comment: In my pom.xml I have: owlapi-distribution (4.5.26) and swrlapi-drools-engine (2.1.2). And when I execute `queryEngine.getTargetQueryEngineName()`and `queryEngine.getTargetQueryEngineVersion()`, I get (respectively) "Drools" and "null". So it seems that Drools is packaged with my swrlapi-drools-engine dependency. I don't use neither Pellet nor Hermit because I have a SWRL rule that uses a `swrlx∶makeOWThing` axiom. When we performed some tests with Protégé, using only Drools (aka no engine enabled), Protégé gave us explanation for inferred axioms. So, how can Protégé perform that ??? Thks